# Python ctypes.CDLL loads my shared library successfully, but I can't see any of my C++ functions

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes, nvcc

Building a shared (.so) library with nvcc for a small C++ project. When I load this library in python with ctypes.CDLL(), the operation seems to succeed.  But when I look at the resulting object with dir(libc), all I see are built-in methods, not any of my C++ functions from the library.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I needed to have extern "C" preceeding the function declarations in my .h file.